# How to handle event when pointer moves in multiple pointers?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, multi-touch

From the Docs - https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/gestures/multi

> Use the getActionIndex() function with ACTION_POINTER_UP and ACTION_POINTER_DOWN events only. Don't use this function with ACTION_MOVE events, as this always returns 0.

So, How can I handle the

The current code, not working.

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            val pointerId = event.getPointerId(event.actionIndex)
            val eventX = event.getX(event.actionIndex).toInt()
            val eventY = event.getY(event.actionIndex).toInt()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

`event.actionIndex` always returns `0` as mentioned in the Docs and so I am able to handle only the movement of the first touch when there are multiple touches.

Comment: Read the paragraph in the documentation above the one you quote.

Answer (score 0):

As the docs say - use the down an up events to save the pointer ids and then use them in the move event to get the coordinates.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/gestures/multi#keep-track-of-pointers